# How to change layer parent in python in Gimp?

Tags: python, gimp, gimpfu

Simple problem. I want to change the parent of LayerA to GroupB.
The member "parent" of layer is read only, and I can't use pdb.gimp_image_insert_layer because the layer already has been added to image. I also tried removing it first by gimp_image_remove_layer, and it also doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: "and it also doesn't work" - what happens? How is that different from what is supposed to happen?

Comment: If I use "gimp_image_remove_layer" and then "gimp_image_insert_layer" this is what happens: **Calling error for procedure 'gimp-image-insert-layer':
Procedure 'gimp-image-insert-layer' has been called with an invalid ID for argument 'layer'. Most likely a plug-in is trying to work on a layer that doesn't exist any longer.** As for "How is that different from what is supposed to happen?", I don't understand the question. I'm just experimenting, I don't know how Gimp functions work internally. I thought that maybe it would let me use remove and then insert functions, but alas.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find an API for this in Python. Using image.remove_layer() deletes the layer so it cannot be re-inserted, so the best I can think of is to copy the layer using something like this:

```
def moveLayer(image,layer,group,position):
    layerName=layer.name
    layerCopy=layer.copy()
    image.remove_layer(layer)
    layerCopy.name=layerName # Can't have two layers with same name
    image.insert_layer(layerCopy,group,position)
    return layerCopy # this one has a new ID
```

This said, I've written many Python scripts and never needed to change a layer parent, so maybe there is a way to avoid doing this...

Comment: Thanks, that will do. By the way, is there any recent documentation on gimp python? I just mostly use "browse" in gimp python console, and dir() function.

Comment: So do I... there is also [this](https://www.gimp.org/docs/python/) but not that complete.